# Snowflake SQL: Get Multiple Columns based on Values in One column of a Table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In my FROM clause, I created a *virtual table* [which gets data from multiple actual tables] that contains PatientID, ProcedureCode, ProcedureDate, and RowNum columns. A patient commonly has multiple procedures on a single date.

It looks like this:

| PatientID | ProcedureCode | ProcedureDate | RowNum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 2023-06-27 | 1 |
| 1 | 234 | 2023-06-27 | 2 |
| 1 | 345 | 2023-06-27 | 3 |
| 1 | 456 | 2023-06-27 | 4 |

I would like my Select statement to show each ProcedureCode for each Patient in a separate column so that the output looks like this:

| PatientID | Procedure1 | Procedure2 | Procedure3 | Procedure4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | 234 | 345 | 456 |

I would appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to use pivot function if the number of procedure is defined.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM <virtual table>
    PIVOT(MAX(PatientID) FOR ProcedureCode IN ('Procedure1', 'Procedure2', 'Procedure3', 'Procedure4'))
      AS p (PatientID_renamed, Procedure1, Procedure2, Procedure3,Procedure4)
  ORDER BY PatientID_renamed;
```

Comment: Thanks. My virtual Table is one of several Tables being used in the From clause. It will join to one of the other Tables using PatientID. The Number of Procedures can vary from two or three - up to 20.